# How to provide the function signature for a function taking iterators of stl containers?

Tags: c++, function, templates, stl, c++14

I want to write a function `my_func` that can be called as so, but does not care that `v` is a `std::vector`, it could be any STL container. A bit like `std::for_each`:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {...};
my_func(v.begin(), v.end());
```

But I cannot figure out the function signature.

```
void my_func(??? i1, ??? i2)
{
  std::for_each(i1, i2, ...); // dumb example implementation
}
```

I am not great at template programming so even looking at the function declaration for `std::for_each` is not helping me.

Is there an easy implementation or is this fundamentally going to get messy with template vars?

Comment: You must use templates. Each iterator is a distinct type. There is no common superclass for all iterators in the C++ library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on how generic you want the function to be.  If the iterator types have to match, then

```
template <typename T>
void my_func(T i1, T i2)
{
    std::for_each(i1,i2,...); //dumb example implementation
}
```

is all you need.  If you want them to be able to be different, then you just need another template parameter like

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void my_func(T i1, U i2)
{
    std::for_each(i1,i2,...); //dumb example implementation
}
```

Finally, if you don't like dealing with templates you can use a lambda instead and let the compiler take care of this for you.  That would give you

```
auto my_func = [](auto i1, auto i2)
{
    std::for_each(i1,i2,...); //dumb example implementation
};
```

Comment: In my use-case (in the question), would I have to specify `T` when calling it or would the compiler infer thi?

Comment: @Mr.Boy The compiler will infer it for you.

Comment: Also neat idea about declaring a lambda object

Comment: @Mr.Boy Thanks.  Lambdas can be super useful.  They are one of my favorite features of modern C++.

Comment: Actually using lambda/auto, I can pass the container itself as a single object and call `.begin()` / `.end()` on it

Comment: @Mr.Boy If that is what you want, you can do the same thing with  `template <typename T>
void my_func(T const & c)
{
    std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(),...); //dumb example implementation
}`

Answer (score 8):

You could write a templated function

```
template<typename Iterator>
void my_func(Iterator startIter, const Iterator endIter)
{
  std::for_each(startIter, endIter, /* lambda */);
}
```

---

In case of wondering, how to pass the third parameter of the `std::for_each`, you could provide one more template parameter

```
const auto defaultCallable = [](auto element){ }; // does nothing
template<typename Iterator, typename Callable = decltype(defaultCallable)>
void my_func(Iterator startIter, const Iterator endIter, Callable func = {})
{
    std::for_each(startIter, endIter, func);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The syntax is not *too* obscure! The following way uses the range `for` at the point of use:

```
template <template<typename...> class Iterable, typename T>
void foo(
    const Iterable<T>& y // the container
){
    for (auto&& e : y){
        // e is the 'thingy' in the container.
    }
}
```

and you can pass any iterable container of arbitrary type to `foo`.

Comment: interesting approach to abstract even iterators out, though not sure if this is what OP would call "easy" (template template parameters arent the most accesible thing)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I fixed the indentation, come on it's easy!

Comment: If you wanted it to be generic, `T` would need to be a parameter pack.  Otherwise `template<typename> class Iterable` would do the job. But I don't see the benefit of this over just have a single `typename T` with a `const T & y` parameter. Edit : I guess the solution with the ellipsis covers cases like `std::vector` which has multiple template parameters, but only the first one doesn't have a default type. But a simple template argument would cover that too.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: But it is a thing of beauty! Perhaps this answer is not necessarily aimed at the OP: answers don't need to be.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux; perhaps. Other folk have dealt with the "StartIt" "EndIt" approach.

Comment: What if I want to pass a template with a non-type parameter (Like `std::array<T, N>`?). It seems unnecessary to get the template when you can just work with the class: `template<class Iterable> void foo(const Iterable& y);`

Comment: @Artyer: My goal here was to offer something up that permitted the range-`for` in the implementation. Yes, this is far from being the only way.

Comment: @Bathsheba My concern is that I don't understand the benefit of this solution over just a single template argument. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/V89f7A).

Comment: @Bathsheba completely agree on the beauty thingy, its only of the usefulness in this context you had to convince me ;).

Comment: _Note to self:_ Just go and buy that book on templates already!

Comment: It's definitely not my style (I'm the OP) but I still appreciate a good answer - thanks.